# Android MediaStore.Files.getContentUri how to get a folder internal to the app

Tags: android, mediastore

In my app, I am trying to build a image gallery to display the images taken using the app from a folder created within the app.

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
//        File imageDestPath = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "cropped");
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE
        };
        String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE
                + " OR "
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + " = "
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

        return new CursorLoader( this,
                MediaStore.Files.getContentUri( "external" ),
                projection,
                selection,
                null,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"
                );
    }
```

I am using the above code to get the files from the folder.  However, the above code uses:

```
MediaStore.Files.getContentUri( "external" ),
```

the external directory.  This displays the images in my DCIM/Camera folder of the phone.  When I tried to change this to an internal folder, I am not getting any images.  I tried the following:

```
File imageDestPath = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "cropped");
```

and used the `imageDestPath` in

```
MediaStore.Files.getContentUri( imageDestPath ),  //not working
MediaStore.Files.getContentUri( "internal" ),  //not displaying any images - no error
MediaStore.Files.getContentUri( getFilesDir.getName() ),  //not displaying any images - no error
MediaStore.Files.getContentUri( getFilesDir()+"cropped" ),  //not displaying any images - no error
```

I think I have not understood the MediaStore.Files.getContentUri part correctly.  When I attach the `imageDestPath` to a Toast, it displays the folder correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I tried to change this to an internal folder, I am not getting any images

`MediaStore` has no access to those images, and `getContentUri()` does not support [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).